# Wrong Order ID - PayPal IPN Exception Magento 2

Tags: orders, paypal, payment, order-status, ipn

I keep getting the following email from PayPal:

```
Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications 
(IPN). Instant Payment Notifications sent to the following URL(s) are 
failing: 

http://mywebsite.com/paypal/ipn/ 

If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider that 
is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider with the 
above information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be disabled for your 
account. 

Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue. 

Yours sincerely,
```

So, I checked my var/log/exception.log, and found the following message:

```
[2018-02-20 03:33:12] main.CRITICAL: Wrong order ID: "000000012". 
{"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Wrong order ID: \"000000012\". 
at /home/admin/web/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-
paypal/Model/Ipn.php:140)"} []
```

We've been getting this email all weekend, and the only 2 orders it's happened for is 000000011 and 000000012, however these orders aren't orders within Magento sales (we're currently on order 000000026 or something).

Has anybody gotten any ideas please?

Much appriciated

Comment: have you fixed?

Comment: what's the solution?

Comment: Refer to the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with something missing up.

2 orders skipped a order ID causing the order ID from PayPal not exist (thus the error).

For example, the order ID in Magento was 21 although in PayPal (can't remember it exactly) it was 12.

The same thing happened with the other order.

This has now stopped with all other orders (only seemed to happen with them orders which must of glitched) as I've had quiet a few which have run perfectly fine since.

Comment: can you please explain more to resolve this issue

Comment: I've updated the answer above

Comment: Thanks, so you didn't find a solution how to solve it then? It just automatically stopped  happening? My is still happening and I have no idea how to fix it...

Comment: Hi Bare Feet. Fortunately it did stop by itself. Check the error log and see if it's just for one or 2 order. Although I was getting the error every day, it was only for 2 orders due to PayPal re sending the IPN up to 15 times. We rang PayPal, and they said if however the account does get suspended from sending IPNs, they can reactivate it instantly again. After this we haven't had the error again.

Answer (score 1):

This error was noticed when run magento2 instance. I noticed that this will some times come if you change anything related to the getOrder , Order Confirmation.
For the fresh installation this won't be an issue.
I recommend to go through your changes done related to any sales/orders/invoices etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after some hours debug and check files debug.log, exception.log, payment.log, I found the issue is

```
Numeric value out of range: 167 Out of range value for column 'sequence_value' at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `sequence_invoice_1` () VALUES ()
```

Then I go to table sequence_invoice_1 and have changed type of "sequence_value" from int(10) to bigint(20). Now, it works fine.

Our customer have a lot order migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2. That is an issue.

Alothemes - Happy Coding!